# SQL Select statement in a Class module need table field in If Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am building a Class Module with MS Access 2007 with a VBA SQL Statement to sendsave down a file and send two different e-mails out. I keep getting Variable not defined for the field MWStatus in the Status_Tbl. I am blind to all the code now and need help. I had the SQL statement in the module behind the form and it worked, but was slowing down the form, so I am moving the SQL statement. My question is, why is the Field MWStatus in the Status_Tbl giving me the error "Variable not defined". This is my first time putting the SQL statement in VBA Module and I don't know if I did it right

```vb
Public Sub SendConfirm()
On Error GoTo Err_SendConfirm_Click

Dim Borrower As String, LOEmail As String, ProcEmail As String, ClsEmail As String, Caution As String, LNumber As Long, TheFile As String, TheName As String

'SQL Statement to get Processor and Closer email
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strCMCID As String
strCMCID = Me!CMCID_Txt.Value
strSQL = "SELECT Commitments_Tbl.CMCID, Status_Tbl.MWStatus, DBUsers_Tbl.EMail, DBUsers_Tbl_1.EMail " & _
"FROM ((Commitments_Tbl LEFT JOIN Status_Tbl ON Commitments_Tbl.LoanNumber = Status_Tbl.LoanNumber) LEFT JOIN DBUsers_Tbl AS DBUsers_Tbl_1 ON Status_Tbl.Processor = DBUsers_Tbl_1.MWName) LEFT JOIN DBUsers_Tbl ON Status_Tbl.Closer = DBUsers_Tbl.MWName " & _
"WHERE Commitments_Tbl.CMCID)= ' " & strCMCID & " ' ; "

'Message Box
Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response

LOEmail = Me!OrigID_Cbo.Column(3)
Borrower = Me!BorrNameL_Txt
LNumber = Nz(Me!LoanNumber_Txt, 0)

Msg = "Do you want to send an e-mail to Set_up?"
Style = vbYesNo
Title = "Cancel Set-Up E-Mail"
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
If Response = vbYes Then
    GoTo line3
Else
    GoTo line4
End If

line3:
TheName = "" & Borrower & " " & LNumber & ""
TheFile = "P:\mortgage\prodcenters\LOAN ITEMS (SW)\_RateLocks_and_Changes\" & TheName & ".rtf"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Confirmation_Email2", acFormatRTF, TheFile, False

If Nz(Me!InvestorID_Cbo, "Blank") = "Blank" Then
  DoCmd.SendObject , , , "CommerceMortgage@CommerceBank.com", , , "New Lock: " & Borrower & ": " & LNumber, "A rate lock confirmation has been saved down to the server at P:\mortgage\prodcenters\LOAN ITEMS (SW)\_RateLocks_and_Changes as a word document with the same name and loan number as that is the subject line of this email. Please upload it into the GDR.", -1
Else
    DoCmd.SendObject , , , "CommerceMortgage@CommerceBank.com", , , "Term Change" & ": " & Borrower & ": " & LNumber, "A rate lock confirmation has been saved down to the server at P:\mortgage\prodcenters\LOAN ITEMS (SW)\_RateLocks_and_Changes as a word document with the same name and loan number as that is the subject line of this email. Please upload it into the GDR.", True
End If

line4:
    ClsEmail = Nz([DBUsers_Tbl_1.EMail], "John.Vanesler@CommerceBank.com")
    ProcEmail = Nz([DBUsers_Tbl.EMail], "John.Vanesler@CommerceBank.com")
If Me!RateExpDate_Txt <= Date + 8 Then
    Caution = "STOP Terms Finalized:"
ElseIf ***MWStatus*** = "Closing" And Me!RateExpDate_Txt >= Date + 8 Then
    Caution = "STOP:"
Else
    Caution = ""
End If
If Me!InvestorID_Cbo = "" Then
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Confirmation_Email", "SnapshotFormat(*.snp)", LOEmail, ProcEmail & ";" & ClsEmail, , Caution & "New Lock: " & Borrower & ": " & LNumber, , True
Else
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Confirmation_Email", "SnapshotFormat(*.snp)", LOEmail, ProcEmail & ";" & ClsEmail, , Caution & "  " & "Term Change" & ": " & Borrower & ": " & LNumber, , True
End If

Exit_SendConfirm_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_SendConfirm_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_SendConfirm_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question exactly..?

Comment: @Dan Thank you for looking at this post. Back story, I had the SQL statement in the module behind the form and it worked, but was slowing down the form, so I am moving the SQL statement. My question is, why is the Field MWStatus in the Status_Tbl giving me the error "Variable not defined". This is my first time putting the SQL statement in VBA Module and I don't know if I did it right.

Comment: @Dan I don't think I put your name in correct so I did it again. Sorry if you get contacted twice.

Comment: No worries, @user3258917.

Answer (score 2):

Your table, *Status_Tbl*, includes a field named *MWStatus*.  And your code builds a `SELECT` statement which includes that field.

However, the code doesn't do anything with that `SELECT` statement.  So when this line is evaluated ...

```vb
ElseIf MWStatus = "Closing" And Me!RateExpDate_Txt >= Date + 8 Then
```

... Access interprets *MWStatus* to be an undeclared variable.

If you want *MWStatus* to refer to a field returned by the `SELECT` query, open the query with [OpenRecordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx).  Then you can reference the value of *MWStatus* in the recordset's current row ...

```vb
YourRecordsetObjectVariableName.Fields("MWStatus").Value ' .Value not strictly required here
YourRecordsetObjectVariableName!MWStatus ' same value, but more concise
```

Comment: I feel bad for asking but I am just not getting it. The part I am missing is "YourRecordsetObjectVariableName" 
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strCMCID As String
Dim strMWS As String

strCMCID = Me!CMCID_Txt.Value
strSQL = "SELECT Commitments_Tbl.CMCID, Status_Tbl.MWStatus, DBUsers_Tbl.EMail, DBUsers_Tbl_1.EMail " & _
"FROM ..."WHERE Commitments_Tbl.CMCID)= ' " & strCMCID & " ' ; "

Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
strMWS = rst!MWStatus

Comment: Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strCMCID As String
    Dim strMWS As String

    strCMCID = Me!CMCID_Txt.Value
    strSQL = "SELECT Commitments_Tbl.CMCID, Status_Tbl.MWStatus, DBUsers_Tbl.EMail, DBUsers_Tbl_1.EMail " & _
"FROM ..."WHERE Commitments_Tbl.CMCID)= ' " & strCMCID & " ' ; "

    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    strMWS = rst!MWStatus

Comment: Now I'm getting Object Variable not set. I'm I correct, I am also trying to pull in from the SQL DBUsers_Tbl.EMail and DBUsers_Tbl_!.EMail do I need to do the same for them? This is my first time using this site, so sorry for the messy posting.

Comment: Would this help me? Once I get this I will be so happy.

Comment: Have you ever written VBA code which opens a DAO recordset and reads values from that recordset?  I'm asking because I'm getting the impression you are lost with that topic.

Comment: No I have not, this is my first time doing this. Right now I fill the word "Lost" is a little lacking. :)

Comment: I had the tables in the SQL statement behind the form and the code worked, but was slowing down the form that is for data entry. I only needed the three other tables to send the emails out and to save down a report. So I wanted to move the SQL statement to VBA and not bog down the form.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Look at the Access "Database.OpenRecordset Method" help topic.  It's an important topic when you're doing Access VBA.  Post a new question if you need help with your code.  Use a simple VBA procedure which excludes everything else ... such as `DoCmd.SendObject` Ignore that stuff until after you get the recordset piece working.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting this error when trying to execute strSQL (which is somewhere outside this Sub). It looks like this error is showing because the field MWStatus does not exist in table Status_Tbl.

Comment: I checket the table and field name and it is there. Should I break out the SQL statement?